# Write custom gutenberg css classes to css file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

So i am creating a custom gutenberg and currently i have build it using the color theme from the brand so is used thr `getColorClassName` to generate the css class for when a color is added to the gutenberg.

I have the theme css with root variables

```
:root {
    --colorRed: #dd0d0d;
    --colorWhite: #fff;
}
```

I passed a `gutenbergTheme` attribute that is set by the `PanelColorSetting` in Inspector control and then generate a className with `getColorClassName('color', attribute)` and then a class is generated like `.has-white-color` for example.

I then manually write the styling for this class in the theme css like

```
.has-white-color {
    color: var(--colorWhite);
}
```

This works but not good enough in the sense that a change can require me to change multiple files.

The question is, is there a way to dynamically generate the css classes in the gutenberg.php file and then write those classes to the css file when the gutenberg is used?